# Reachable area of cannonball given fixed initial speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

The trajectory of a cannonball fired from the origin with initial speed $v_0$ at an angle $\theta$ is given by
$$y = x\tan\theta - \frac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2\theta}x^2.$$
For fixed $v_0$, at what angle $\theta$ should the canon ball be fired so that it will hit a target located at $(x_0,y_0)$? What is the area of the region in which the target can be located such that it is possible to hit the target?

Comment: I'm a little confused: what do you mean by "field"?

Comment: Same here.If you want to say that max. area that the ball can cover at different angles?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Contour might be a better word to use, for theta from 0 to 180 degree, the furthest point the cannonball can hit can be connected as a contour line.

Comment: @007 I think you get what I mean max area is right:)

Comment: OK, so then: what exactly is giving you trouble with this problem? You mentioned that you have two variables which you want to combine into one, or something like that - why do you say you need to do that? Could you show the work you've done so far and the step you get stuck at?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky hope my latest edit explain myself, like I said, I don't really know how to get this max area equation, reducing variable is just a guess..

Comment: Your edit does help, we're getting there. What are the meanings of the variables $x$ and $y$ in the part you edited into your question? Are those supposed to be horizontal coordinates? If so, I would suggest changing the notation of the projectile equation you included, because that equation uses $y$ as a vertical coordinate.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky x is for horizontal coordinates and y is for vertical. I don't understand what you mean.. (x,y) is a conventional coordinate point isn't it? And that equation shouldn't be changed either in my opinion...

Comment: OK, then the question is correct as is, but then what do you mean by the max area the cannonball can hit? Are you not talking about an area on the ground around the cannon?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky No, I'm coding a simple 2D game not 3D, so there's only x and y axis.. I see why you were confused earlier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8589/discussion-between-david-zaslavsky-and-arch1tect)

Comment: Consider using $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}=1+\tan^2\theta$ to obtain a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$, with coefficients dependent on $x,y,v_0$.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please see [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/7433). We expect homework and homework-like problems to have some effort put into them, and deal with conceptual issues. If you edit your question to explain (1) What you have tried, (2) the concept you have trouble with, and (3) your level of understanding, I'll be happy to reopen this. (Flag this message for ♦ attention with a custom message, or reply to me in the comments with `@Manishearth` to notify me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y = x\tan\theta - \frac{g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2\theta}x^2.$$

$$y=x.\tan\theta-\dfrac{gx^2}{2v_0^2}-\dfrac{gx^2\tan^2\theta}{2v_0^2}$$

$$A\tan^2\theta+B\tan\theta+C=0$$

As $\tan\theta\in\Bbb R$ , so $B^2-4AC\ge0$ must hold, for the above equation to have real roots for $\tan\theta$.

Use that and you'll get $$y\le \dfrac{v^2}{2g}-\dfrac{g}{2v^2}.x^2 $$

That defines a area under the parabola , within which any target can be hit.

[image]

Comment: OMG, exactly what I want...You mind reader:)

Comment: Is it B^2 - AC or B^2 - 4AC ?

Comment: @Arch1tect Hmm... Yes $4AC$ the $ sign ate up the 4. Thanx.